# NumPy/SciPy FFT for voltage/time data

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, fft

This is a pretty basic question.  I'm trying to use SciPy/NumPy to perform fft on voltage vs. time data from an oscilloscope.  I am completely lost when it comes to passing the data to scipy for fft processing.  I have the data as two lists (x and y values) and obviously can zip the lists to tuple.  I am unsure what to do though.  I can't seem to find much documentation.  Apologies if this has been asked before, I could not locate a relevant question.

To sum up: If a person has x and y data stored in two lists or stored in a tuple, how do they perform FFT on these data?

Comment: Are all time samples equally spaced?

Comment: Hi, did you figure it out? I have a time vs velocity data of 10000 points and the time is evenly spaced out. Can you tell me how can I use python to get the frequency of my data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation can be found at http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.fftpack.fft.html

I am not sure why you want to pass time; surely it is implicit in the sequence of voltage measurements?

In general,

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.fftpack

data = np.arange(0.0, 12.8, 0.1)
fft = scipy.fftpack.fft(data)
```

Comment: You are correct, I suppose I wouldn't have to pass time aside from using it to specify relative time position wrt other waveforms.  This could easily be inferred though from the file name.  Sometimes these obvious things never occur to me.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that all samples are equally spaced (i.e. there is the same difference between each time samples), you just need to pass `y` vector to fft function.

It will returns you a vector of complex numbers. First number will correspond to DC voltage. Then half the vector will be positive frequencies, and the second half will correspond to negative frequencies. If you are only dealing with real voltages, you probably don't need the negatives frequencies.

Here is an example, assuming `x` any `y` are numpy arrays:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
fy = numpy.fft.fft(y)
dt = x[1] - x[0]
n = x.size
freqs = numpy.fft.fftfreqs(n, d=dt) # Frequencies associated with each samples
pyploy.plot(numpy.fft.fftshift(freqs), numpy.fft.fftshift(abs(fy)))
pyplot.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from scipy.fftpack import fft

my_voltage_list = [1.1,1.2,1.1,1.1,3.0,3.1]
my_time_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

fft_result = fft(my_voltage_list)

print fft_result

>>> array([ 10.6 +0.00000000e+00j,   0.1 +3.29089653e+00j,
    -2.0 +4.44089210e-16j,  -0.2 +0.00000000e+00j,
    -2.0 -4.44089210e-16j,   0.1 -3.29089653e+00j])
```